# print error if there is a name already in the table

Tags: sql-server

//My code should be something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE REGISTRATION
@USERNAME VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN IF
SELECT USERNAME FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME =  @USERNAME 
PRINT 'USER ALREADY EXITS'
ELSE
IF @USERNAME = 'NULL'
PRINT 'Fill username'
end
end
```

Comment: `IF EXISTS(SELECT username FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ...` or `@@ROWCOUNT` might be what you want, but this shouldn't be done in the database, better check if the user exists or null by checking the query result instead.

Comment: can you type that query if possible

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE REGISTRATION
@USERNAME VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
declare @count as int
select @count = COUNT(*) from USER where USERNAME =@USERNAME
if(@count > 0)
print 'USER ALREADY EXITS'  -- Record Exists
else
print 'Fill username'  -- NULL
end
```

Answer (score 0):

use exists. Also, formatting gets overlooked and is important

```
CREATE PROCEDURE REGISTRATION
@USERNAME VARCHAR(20)=''
AS
BEGIN
    IF exists(SELECT 1 FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME =  @USERNAME)
        begin
            PRINT 'USER ALREADY EXITS'
        end
    ELSE
        begin
            PRINT 'Fill username'
        end
end
```